# Superscript text is hard to distinguish from the line above

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In [Design reason why .NET does not have a conceptual (Fatal-)Error exception type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830217/design-reason-why-net-does-not-have-a-conceptual-fatal-error-exception-type) the author chose to use superscript to make an aside.  It ended up being hard to read because there is very little spacing between the top of the superscript and the bottom of the previous line as shown below:

> [image: Sample picture of superscript text]

Can a little bit of vertical spacing be added to make the two lines easier to read?

This screenshot was taken on Safari 7, but also reproduced on Firefox 35 (OS X).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some extra styling snuck in here - it'll be corrected next build.