# Why we are using "superscript text"? Is this a bug?

Tags: discussion

I came across [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334782/2279200), strange UI case:

[image]

By inspecting the HTML, the elevated text is inside a [sup tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/sup.html). I have seen this before and again the `sup` text was containing a link.

Is this a bug? Or It is intentional?

I am using Google Chrome (v53), in Windows 10.

Somehow Related: *[Superscript text is hard to distinguish from the line above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283876/superscript-text-is-hard-to-distinguish-from-the-line-above)*

Note: (IMHO) If it is intentional, it is not intuitive.

Comment: Its probably used intentionally by the OP. Or did I miss something from your question, why should it be a bug?

Comment: The OP added that tag in - when editing the post. Given that the `<sup>` element is supported, what's the actual bug here?

Comment: "If it is intentional, it is not intuitive." - appears to be intentional. What exactly is "not intuitive", in your (humble) opinion?

Comment: I did not know that is was intentional (I removed the bug tag). As for "not intuitive", having such a large text on `sup` makes it hard to read and it seems `angly` in the eye (again that's only my opinion)

Comment: It is a side remark to the current sentence; a footnote, if you will, but then inline with the main text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the raw mark down of that post:

> `Note that the user in question has the same username and avatar <sup>(currently [i.stack.imgur.com/MNNJ3.png][1] but it changes often)</sup> as [**this user**][2]. (AKA, originally-ish, "Normal Human")`

That superscript is their intentional left by the OP.

If you like that kind of styling is a matter of taste. It is not a bug, the markdown is used within the boundaries it is designed for.

Answer (score 14):

<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>‌​<sup><sup>It's not a bug</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Comment: did you put that `&zwnj;&#8203;` in the 12th `<sup>`? curious as to what you wanted to achieve with that

Comment: I don't see that :/

Comment: if you go into Chrome (and i assume Firefox as well) and right click on one of the words and go to inspect element [you can see it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4b9HB.png)

Comment: @Memor-X that's SO.  Read the comment thread here http://stackoverflow.com/q/23190056/1228 I'm sure there are a few meta questions about it...